# Google query function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am trying to return multiple records from a logbook into a final monthly statement... I'm using the query function but I do not get multiple records, it only displays the first match.

My sheets are from 1-31 for days of the month, then the last sheet labeled 717 is for Unit #717's monthly statement.
On Sheet 717, I would like to display information from sheets 1 through 31. Where column A=717, display values from columns B,C,D. Currently, it will only show me the first match. The amount column should show the corresponding rate for that row.

I hope my explanation is not confusing, any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Here is a link to [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/a/sizeup.ca/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlD0CkN7ppvRdFJ0MUVlR21ucWk3TnVTQ0NFNjBiRnc#gid=0).

Answer (score 0):

As you are concatenating the output of QUERY functions, you are actually performing an "array calculation", and you'll need use an "array calculation enabler", otherwise you will indeed only get the first applicable result.

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY('1'!A3:G60;"select B where A=717")&QUERY('1'!A3:G60;"select C where A=717")&QUERY('1'!A3:G60;"select D where A=717"))`